# Asignar usuario y permisos a BBDD SQL mediante Script

Tags: sql

Realizando una migración de numerosas BBDD, necesitamos asignar un usuario de Windows y los permisos de este a cada una de las bases de datos restauradas.

¿Podría hacerse esto mediante un scritp? De esta manera se evitaría repetir el mismo proceso tantas veces.

El usuario a añadir es el usuario de red para servicios, NETWORK (Windows User).

Comment: Este enlace quizás puede ayudarte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987190/scripting-sql-server-permissions

Comment: Nombre de gestor de BD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto me ha funcionado:

```
USE [DDBB_NAME]
GO
CREATE USER [USER_NAME] 
GRANT 
ALTER, CONNECT,CREATE TABLE, DELETE, 
EXECUTE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE
ON DATABASE::[DDBB_NAME] TO [USER_NAME]
```